# Adanced Filter VBA Issue

Tags: excel, filter, vba

I have a large table of data and my goal is to advanced filter that table by  Column B from sheet 2.

I defined my variables as ws0 (where the data I am filtering is) is my Sheet1 and ws02 is my Sheet2 (where the filter criteria is).  It's just not working, I can get it to work if i specify the exact ranges but I want this to find the last row on sheet two as that range of data will change.  Here is my code:  I would also love to be able to find the last from from ws0 as well..but one step at a time :)

```
Dim LastRow As Long

With ws02
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With


ws0.Range("A1:I3000").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
    ws02.Range("B1").LastRow, Unique:=False


End Sub
```

If anyone can help I'd greatly appreciate it!!

[Here is Sheet 1](http://imgur.com/4akU8Uw) 
[Here is Sheet 2](http://imgur.com/9rH6XSv)

Comment: I suspect it is because `LastRow` is a long, so you'll get just a number, but you haven't told excel which range that number belongs to.  It appears like you are trying to use the `Long` as a `Range`.  You probably need something like `CriteriaRange:=ws02.Range("B" & LastRow)` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
CriteriaRange:= _
    ws02.Range("B1").LastRow
```

To

```
CriteriaRange:= _
    ws02.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
```

You are attempting to use `LastRow` as a property or a method of the `Range` object, but no such property or method exists.

This will use the criteria from cell B2 to the last row in column B.

Comment: This is all great help!  When I do that though the data doesn't filter, I don't get an error which is good but nothing filters in the table..is my filter code wrong?  Or is it for some reason seeing nothing in my column B on Sheet 2?

Comment: How are you setting `ws01` and `ws0`?  Are those properly set?

Comment: Dim wb0 As Workbook
Dim ws0 As Worksheet, ws02 As Worksheet

Set ws0 = wb0.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws02 = wb0.Sheets("Sheet2")

This is how I have my workbook and two worksheets defined

Comment: Are you trying to filter based on all of the values in Column B?  Or just the last value?

Comment: All of the values, so technicall B2 to the last row, as B1 is the header

Comment: Ah that makes way more sense, let me update my answer and see if it helps more

Comment: I appreciate all of the help! It's still not filtering the data, i must be missing something small somewhere, so should I be changing lastRow from Long to Range when I define it?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I will be much more useful without seeing Sheet1 and Sheet2.  Any way you could post sample data?

Comment: I just put in hyperlinks to imgur photos..What I want to do is advanced filter Sheet 1's data by column B on Sheet 2 so can the Column A data that didn't load correctly the first time.  It shouldn't be an issue with how I defined sheet2 because I use sheet 2 earlier in the code and it works fine

Comment: AHHHH it worked!!!! I had it as xlDown and needed to change it back to up! You're the best!